# executing a script when at a specific classNN

Tags: class, focus, controls, autohotkey

How shouuld I tweak the following script so that the hotkey is activated not at ANY moment where I'm at the class shown (that is Outlook) but at a specific sub window ( the preview pane of the Inbox box (whose classNN is _WwG1 )) ?

```
 #IfWinActive ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32
+!m::
        ControlFocus, OutlookGrid1, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32
        if ErrorLevel   ; i.e. it's not blank or zero.
        MsgBox, You don't seem to be in context.
       return
    #IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the hotkey look for active controls once it is activated.  This way you can use the same hotkey for multiple commands, each command depending on the control.  You can do this with several if/else statements to test for the subcontrols.

- The hotkey only works in Outlook.
- Each control has its own command
- Each command is limited to that particular control

  ```
  #ifwinactive, ahk_exe outlook.exe
  {
  +!m::
      controlgetfocus, thiscontrol
      if(thiscontrol = "_Wwg1"){
            ControlFocus, OutlookGrid1, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32
            if ErrorLevel   ; i.e. it's not blank or zero.
            MsgBox, You seem to focused on %thiscontrol%
      }else if(thiscontrol = "_Wsg2){
          msgbox, you've discovered the second control!
      }
  return
  }
  ```